# Why is my function coming up undefined the second time it is being called?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my method

```
private onDataLoadSuccessful(users: User[], roles: Role[]) {

    this.alertService.stopLoadingMessage();
    this.loadingIndicator = false;
    this.dataSource.data = users.map(data => {
        let newData: User;
        newData = Utilities.toCamel((data));
        return newData;
    });

    this.allRoles = roles.map(function (data) {
        let newData: Role;
        newData = Utilities.toCamel(data);
        return newData;
    });
}
```

I am calling `Utilities.toCamel(data)` twice. The first time to get convert the `Users[]` to camel case and the second time the `Roles[]`

The second time it is called :

```
 this.allRoles = roles.map(function (data) {
        let newData: Role;
        newData = Utilities.toCamel(data);
        return newData;
    });
```

It causes this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toCamel' of undefined`

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: you have to use arrow function `() => {}` instead of `function()` to refer the correct Utilities object.

Comment: Why are you the `function` key word in the second call, and not an arrow function like the first?

Comment: I was trying to see if I used a function instead of the arrow notation would it make a difference. Originally, I was the arrow function and it still gave me the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like the first time:

```
this.allRoles = roles.map(data => {
    let newData: Role;
    newData = Utilities.toCamel(data);
    return newData;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. ;-) !! That was it. The first time I think I had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use arrow function i.e. `() =>` instead of function keyword. Like this:

```
this.allRoles = roles.map( (data) => {
    let newData: Role;
    newData = Utilities.toCamel(data);
    return newData;
});
```